# Reloading a web page with ajax from a second web service url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

i have a page which gets its data from a web service that have specific url , 
i'm doing some traitement (a checkbox multiple choices) ,  and i wanna make my same page reload and get its data from a second webservice from a second url recuper its data .

here is my js block of recupering data for the first time :

```
var find_freelance = {
        page: [$('[data-page="mypage"]')],
        route: {

              getdata: back + 'api/webservice1',
        },
        block: {
            resume: $(""),
        },

        init: function () {
            console.log(find_freelance.page);
            for (var i in find_freelance.page) {
                if (find_freelance.page[i].length) {
                    this.getData();
                }
            }
        },
getData: function () {

            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: find_freelance.route.getfreelance,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    matchDataHtml(data);
                    matchDataHtmlFor(data);
                    matchDataHtmIf(data);
                    customTraitement()
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        },
```

Now i wanna that page reload after a custum action (**customTraitement()** )
from  the second webservice of response.

> " api/webservice2

**how can i do it , any suggestions ??**

Comment: Why you need to reload the page? You can just use the success result there itself.

Comment: i wanna handle the multiple form of responses that my server can give

Answer (score 0):

Add at the final sentence in the ajax function `"return false;"`

getData: function () {

```
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: find_freelance.route.getfreelance,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                matchDataHtml(data);
                matchDataHtmlFor(data);
                matchDataHtmIf(data);
                customTraitement()
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        return false;
        });
    },
```

Comment: i  need to load a second one , not just stopping the first one